Twincat compare a FB with interface
In my project, I've developed FB_Modes that allow me to perform certain actions depending on the mode. These FBs implement the same I_Mode interface.
To check which mode is active, I'd like to compare the current I_Mode with an FB, but Twincat doesn't allow direct comparison between an FB and an interface. I'd like to be able to do something like this.
IF fbMachine.itfActualMode = fbMode2 THEN
    <Do something>
END_IF

Is there a way to do this? Or another way to directly compare FBs with the interface with the address.
To get around this problem, I use a unique property for each FB. But I use STRING comparison and I think this solution is not clean.
IF fbMachine.itfActualMode.sName = fbMode2.sName THEN
    <Do something>
END_IF


One solution is to add a method Equals() to the I_Mode and then implement it in the function blocks. Idea is to create a temporary interface and then compare if they match.
METHOD Equals : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    Compare : I_Mode;
END_VAR
VAR
    Temp : I_Mode;
END_VAR

//Code starts
Temp := THIS^;

Equals := Compare = Temp;

Then you can check if the FB is equal to the interface like this
IF fbMachine.itfActualMode.Equals(fbMode2) THEN
    //...
END_IF

This only checks if the instances match. So it doesn't compare types, as the Guiorgy's answer does.

Nice idea, and you could make a TypeEquals method to hide magic numbers/strings/enums inside the method to make comparing types easier.

I once tried to use the built-in __QUERYPOINTER function to check if the current interface is an instance of a specified FunctionBlock, however, as the documentation states at the end (You have to make sure of the type. For example, the interface could offer a method that returns a type code.), it didn't work. The only sensible thing to do seems to be as that quote in the documentation suggested, to add a method/property to the interface that gives information on the current type, as you have already concluded.
The only thing I'd suggest doing is maybe returning a custom enum instead of string, which would allow you to check the type in a case-of statement:
result := '';
fbType := _interface.GetType();
CASE fbType OF
  FbType.FB1: result := 'FB1';
  FbType.FB2: result := 'FB2';
ELSE
  result  := 'unknown';
END_CASE

